# Подключение по RDP в существующую сессию

Tags: rdp, сессия

Есть стимбокс, на стимбоксе стоит windows 8. Стимбокс сам по себе входит в мой аккаунт, и иногда (например, если я поставил его просто играть музыку) требуется подключиться прямо в эту сессию и удаленно пошаманить. Как это осуществить? Подключаюсь через Remmin'у, текущий успех - только окно для нового логина, которое не позволяет мне зайти под уже зашедшим юзером. Teamviewer ставить не хотелось бы, хотя требуется именно его функционал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько понимаю Вы подключаетесь из *nix`ов? Замечал такое: Реммина при РДП подключении начинает почему-то другой сеанс, видимо косяк Реммины.
 Есть одна возможность функционала РДП- насколько помню, нужно что бы была включена ф-ция запроса помощи у удаленного помощника, тогда можно включиться в текущую сессию - но в этом случае требуется подтверждение подключения на стимбоксе.
И не забывайте погуглить:
[Удаленное управление сеансом пользователя windows стандартными средствами](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147273/)
[Remote Tools и Windows 7](http://itband.ru/2011/03/remote-tools-windows-7/)
[Как из Windows 7/ Vista /XP сделать Терминальный Сервер!](http://darmoroz.narod.ru/rdt/WinXP-TS.html)
Лично моим решением в описываемом Вами случае была бы установка на стимбокс [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html) (не забудьте установить mirror driver) - это лучшее решение, нежели ТимВьювер.

Comment: Ну почему сразу гамно - удобный интерфейс, в котором большинство протоколов работы с удаленным компом присутсвует - чем не радость.  А насчет пушки и воробьев не вполне понял к чему это? Сервер UVNC не настолько тяжел, достаточно надежен (в плане - не падает как гимназистка) имеет возможность передачи фалов - что еще надо? ТС сможет к нему коннектится из под привычной ему Реммины. Почему бы и нет?

Comment: В данном случае UltraVNC просто не нужен. И опять-таки, это тоже не RDP (протокол другой). ЗЫ: По RDP  можно диски расшаривать - вы не знали?

Comment: Насчет UVNC - я высказал свое предпочтение (в отношении слов ТС про Тимвьювер).  Насчет возможностей RDP - в курсе, пользовался.  В конце-концов, мы тут выскажем свои мнения, а решать все-равно ТС.

Comment: Ну, тогда уж не TC, а TS - Topic Starter! А ваше мнение ему тоже пригодится, равно как и моё.

Comment: Именно ТС ибо написано по-русски

Comment: Финальный комментарий: все разрешилось через создание пароля для дефолтного пользователя и подключения rdesktop/xfreerdp прямо из консоли (реммину еще не пробовал) - видимо, затык был в отсутствии пароля. Скорее всего, это можно было пролечить через политики безопасности, но я в них не разбираюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Если в серверных вендах по выходе делать Disconnect вместо Log Off, то сеанс будет продолжен. В восьмёрке - не знаю, не пробовал. А что до Teamviewr'а, то он реально сеанс не разрывает, если правильно настроить.